# How to open an APK file in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: android, archive, file-roller

I'm trying to inspect an APK of an Android app I'm developing.
I was able to open and decompress APK files using the Archive Manager application (file-roller, the standard app for compressed files), but I don't know if it's because of the latest Android Studio IDE changes or if it has to do with Ubuntu 18.04 that now I can't.

If I try to open an APK file with this Archive Manger I fails with a dialog saying:

> Could not open "app-debug.apk"
>
> Archive type not supported.

Comment: I've got another machine with Ubuntu 16.04 on it and the archive manager can open the same APK there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Apktool**](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/)

It is the **perfect** tool for opening and analyzing apk files, and it is cross-platform and open source :D

Answer (score 13):

Workaround: copy [whatever].apk to [whatever].zip

```
cp whatever.apk whatever.zip
```

Then Archive Manager will work with the .zip version

[image]

Comment: Well it doesn't work just by changing the extension from apk to zip. Yes I remember it worked sometimes before but now with the latest Android Studio, SDK it doesn't work. Only default archive app of Windows can open it but not Ubuntu's....

Comment: @user924 odd, it still works for me. Updated answer to include screenshot.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of Android Studio and SDK 28/29 for building?

Comment: or I have to copy and not rename?

Comment: I don't use Android Studio or SDK. The apk's I have were downloaded from various sources.

Comment: Then it's not 100% working solution

Comment: @user924 Feel free to post your superior answer! I will upvote it.

Comment: I confirm the previous comment of @user924 that it doesn't work in Ubuntu 18.04 (for me). Perhaps this is related with the target/min/max API level?